# i am not able to getting mail id and mobile no etc from facebook account

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

We are developing hybrid mobile application,in that we have login page.

we want to login via social network like Facebook and google.we are successfully login from Facebook but we want to fetch Facebook account details like user name,mail id,mobile number and address etc.

i am fetching username only remaining i not getting. please any one help me what i did i mistake and what have to do.Below i given code also please find it.

```js
function fblogin() {
 FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
   alert("if");
   getUserInfo(); // Get User Information.
  } else {
   console.log('Authorization failed.');
  }
 }, {
  scope : 'email'
 });

}

function getUserInfo() {
 FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name, username, password, email, first_name, middle_name, last_name, gender, hometown, birthday'}, function(response) {
  alert("name=" + response.name);
  alert("username=" + response.username);
  alert("password=" + response.password);
  alert("id=" + response.id);
  alert("email=" + response.email);
  alert("first_name=" + response.first_name);
  alert("middle_name=" + response.middle_name);
  alert("last_name=" + response.last_name);
  alert("gender=" + response.gender);
  alert("hometown=" + response.hometown);
  alert("birthday=" + response.birthday);
 });
 $.mobile.navigate("#dashboardPage");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>LoginSN</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
      <!--
       <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
       <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 
      -->
      <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
      <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
      <script src="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
   <script>
     
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
     FB.init({
      appId : '1608113949506014',
      xfbml : true,
      version : 'v2.6'
     });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {
      return;
     }
     js = d.createElement(s);
     js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
   </script>
  </head>
  
     <body style="display: none;">
     
      <div data-role="page" id="loginPage">
       <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
        <h1 id="fb-welcome"></h1>
     <label for="text">User Name:</label><input type="text" name="text" id="unL">
     <label for="text">Password:</label><input type="password" name="text" id="pwdL">
     <a href="#dashboardPage" data-role="button" id="buttonLn">LOGIN</a>
     <a href="#registrationPage" data-role="button" id="buttonRe">REGISRASTION</a>
     <a href="#" data-role="button" id="buttonF" onclick="fblogin()">via Facebook Login</a>
     <a href="#" data-role="button" id="login">via Google Login</a>
     <a href="#" data-role="button" id="buttonT">via Twitter Login</a>
    </div>
      </div>
      
      <div data-role="page" id="registrationPage">
       <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
        <label for="text">Name:</label><input type="text" name="text" id="unR">
     <label for="text">DOB:</label><input type="date" name="text" id="pwdR">
     <label for="text">Contact No:</label><input type="number" name="text" id="pwdR">
     <label for="text">Email ID:</label><input type="email" name="text" id="pwdR">
        <label for="text">User Name:</label><input type="text" name="text" id="unR">
     <label for="text">Password:</label><input type="password" name="text" id="pwdR"> 
     <a href="#loginPage" data-role="button" id="buttonR">Registered</a>
  </div>
      </div>
      
      <div data-role="page" id="dashboardPage">
       <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
        
       </div>
      </div>
      
      <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
      <script src="js/main.js"></script>
      <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
      
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name,email,first_name,last_name'}, function(response) {
    ...
});
```

It is called "Declarative Fields", you have to specifiy the fields you want to get in the API call.

Btw, it is not possible at all to get the phone number or the username (only the real name).

Existing fields of the user table: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/user

Existing permissions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: in a fblogin() their is a scope in that email is passing so we have to pass what ever we want for user account details

Comment: after login through Facebook i want to stored the user facebook accout details and next i logout the app next  i want to login using Facebook account credential to login in my application it is possible ?

Comment: it depends on the user info you want to get. for the email, it´s just called "email". for the user location, it´s called "user_location". i will add a link with all the permissions.

Comment: if you want to store account details, use ajax with your server language. logout is as simple as "FB.logout()". not sure what you mean with "account credentials", just use FB.login to login and FB.getLoginStatus to check if the user is authorized. that´s completely off topic though, this thread is about getting the email (and other data) from a user. that´s what "declarative fields" is about.

Comment: if i get password ?birthday,hometown,username, is also not getting

Comment: read my answer again, i specifically told you that i have added a permissions list. of course you need to authorize the user with the appropriate permissions or you will not get anything. for example, it´s the "user_birthday" permission to get the birthday.

Comment: sorry luschn, i am not get it if have any link please provide

Comment: what link do you need? just use the user_birthday permission in the scope parameter: scope : 'email,user_birthday'

Comment: Any body please help me. i am not able login with facebook account in mobile device, but in worklight console i am successfully login.

Comment: you really should not update your question to fill in my answer. that´s what the answer is for, this makes everything confusing. about login: that seems to be a completely different question, and it is WAY too broad to help you in a serious way.